# Equivalent to RegExp in Kotlin

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

In JavaScript, there's a regex function: `RegExp test()` which gets used a bit like this:

```
new RegExp('/regex/').test('string to match')
```

What this does is it tests for a match in a string. If it finds a match, it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

But I can't seem to find an equivalent on Kotlin, Android. Does anyone know if there's something like this or similar on Kotlin?

Comment: Quick search got me this, https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/regular-expressions. Does that help?

Comment: From that article I found `containsMatchIn` which works well for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html) extension on CharSequence:

```
"string to match".contains(Regex("regex"))
```

Or the [`containsMatchIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/contains-match-in.html) method on Regex:

```
Regex("regex").containsMatchIn("string to match")
```